# angular ng-repeat table need month order

Tags: angularjs

I have simple months table with some data but incomplete. Few months are missing So difficult to match with exact every month. These data has to match with exact month, My month are specified in JSON are in "2015-01","2015-02","2015-03"..... format. But also in disorder. 
Plunker :  http://plnkr.co/edit/rW36ckdEfWW7qDqeYiK8?p=preview

```
$scope.year = [
{"month":"2015-03", "val":"23"},
{"month":"2015-02", "val":"45"},
{"month":"2015-06", "val":"11"},
{"month":"2015-01", "val":"56"},
{"month":"2015-11", "val":"11"},
{"month":"2015-12", "val":"15"}
];
```

Help me to place month values exact below to particular month.

Comment: No. In json, there are missing months like "Apr", "May", "Jul" etc... need blank <td> instead..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use orderBy. `<td ng-repeat="item in year | orderBy: 'month'">`. It will sort your data in ng-repeat. 
But here is a problem with your data. You have empty months. You must fill them.

Answer (score 1):

`item in year | orderBy: 'month'` will short your JSON but you won't get `td` for every month. So instead of this solution you need a little algorithm.

1. Short you JSON object based on month values. You will get:

`[["56",1],["45",2],["23",3],["11",6],["11",11],["15",12]]`

2. Now you can easily iterate this array of array and check which month is present or not. If it present put in a final array of object for angular. So you'll get now:

`[{"month":1,"val":"56"},{"month":2,"val":"45"},{"month":3,"val":"23"},{"month":4,"val":0},{"month":5,"val":0},{"month":6,"val":"11"},{"month":7,"val":0},{"month":8,"val":0},{"month":9,"val":0},{"month":10,"val":0},{"month":11,"val":"11"},{"month":12,"val":"15"}]`

After some thinking i come up with this :

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
  var arr = [];
  var year = [
    {"month":"2015-03", "val":"23"},
    {"month":"2015-02", "val":"45"},
    {"month":"2015-06", "val":"11"},
    {"month":"2015-01", "val":"56"},
    {"month":"2015-11", "val":"11"},
    {"month":"2015-12", "val":"15"}
    ];

  var ob = [], temp = [];

    for(var i=0;i<year.length;i++){
      ob.push([year[i].val, parseInt(year[i].month.split('-')[1])]);
    }

    ob.sort(function(a, b) {return a[1] - b[1]})

    var counter=0;
    for(var i=0; i<12; i++){
      if(ob[counter][1] == (i+1)){
        temp.push({month:ob[counter][1],val:ob[counter][0]})
        counter++;
      } else{
        temp.push({month:(i+1),val:0})
      }
    }

    $scope.year = temp;

});
```

## [Working DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/KfVZL2ZroewzpGQQUG6Z?p=preview)

Comment: Yes i was updating answer. You can check it now @sagSurya. I am mostly done.